# node-postgres: I can't figure out what's wrong with my query? (ERROR: syntax error at or near "a")

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm working on a side project and have hit a bit of a dead end when coming across this error. I've ascertained that it's originating from node-postgres package somewhere, but I see nothing inherently wrong with my query!

Here's my code:

```
router.post("/product/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  if (!id) throw new Error("ID not present");

  if (!validateProductReviewForm(req.body))
    throw new Error("Form not valid. Please fix and try again");

  const { name, email, rating, comment } = req.body;
  const date = new Date();

  const sqlText = `INSERT INTO reviews ("name", email, rating, comment, date, productid) VALUES (${name}, ${email}, ${rating}, ${comment}, ${date}, ${id})`;
  console.log(sqlText);
  const { rows } = await query(sqlText);
  res.send(rows);
});
```

And here is my logged query:

```
INSERT INTO reviews ("name", email, rating, comment, date, productid) VALUES (Bill, jpfdhdl@live.com, 2, testing a review post, Tue Mar 30 2021 17:59:22 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time), 2)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: Single quotes around the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were missing the quote delimiters for the string and date values in your query.  However instead of adding the necessary single quotes to the *sqlText* variable, use a better technique and pass the values as an array.

```
const sqlText = 'INSERT INTO reviews ("name", email, rating, comment, date, productid) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)';
const values = [name, email, rating, comment, date, id];
const { rows } = await query(sqlText, values);
```